# Reply option has been removed from comment actions menu

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, comments, ios-app

In the latest beta version (1.2.2.185) I just noticed the Reply option no longer exists for comments:

> [image]

If this is a bug, can this please be fixed? Otherwise, can it please be added back? I became quite used to it, being a useful shortcut.

Comment: I thought I remembered they got rid of it on purpose. Something about replies being the wrong word, and comments aren't threaded and maybe it causes confusion... I don't agree and want it back too

Comment: @mhlester the only thing that comes to mind is that it's indeed not consistent with the web version, which doesn't have "reply" anywhere but still, think the app is different enough to justify such handy shortcuts.

Answer (score 5):

This was purposefully removed during a refactor, as it was introduced as a beta-only feature, and at the time it seemed that the mentions feature would replace it. (The mentions feature helps you autocomplete a user's name when you type @ in the comment).

After some discussion, we decided to put it back, since it was also available in Android. The feature will be back in beta version 1.2.2.186.

Comment: Thanks! Much appreciated. :)